# Rails/Rspec Make tests pass with http basic authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, http-authentication

Here's my http basic authentication in the application controller file (application_controller.rb)

```
before_filter :authenticate

protected

def authenticate
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
    username == "username" && password == "password"  
  end
end
```

and the default test for the index action of my home controller (spec/controllers/home_controller_spec.rb)

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe HomeController do

describe "GET 'index'" do
  it "should be successful" do
    get 'index'
    response.should be_success
  end
end
```

The test doesn't run because of the authentication method. I could comment out "before_filter :authenticate" to run them but I would like to know if there is way to make them worked with the method.

Thank you!

Comment: As of Rails 6, it looks like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68669816/199712) is the working one.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

**Update** (2013): Matt Connolly has provided a GIST which also works for request and controller specs: http://gist.github.com/4158961

---

Another way of doing this if you have many tests to run and don't want to include it everytime (DRYer code):

**Create a /spec/support/auth_helper.rb file:**

```
module AuthHelper
  def http_login
    user = 'username'
    pw = 'password'
    request.env['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic.encode_credentials(user,pw)
  end  
end
```

**In your test spec file:**

```
describe HomeController do
  render_views

  # login to http basic auth
  include AuthHelper
  before(:each) do
    http_login
  end

  describe "GET 'index'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'index'
      response.should be_success
    end
  end

end
```

Credit [here](http://blog.tristanmedia.com/2010/07/testing-http-basic-authentication-with-rspec-2/) - [Archived site](https://web.archive.org/web/20201022092340/http://blog.tristanmedia.com/2010/07/testing-http-basic-authentication-with-rspec-2/)

Comment: it shows request is nil for me. any idea how to get a workaround?

Comment: For request specs, you can have multiple requests, so `request` is `nil`.  Instead you need to create an env hash `env = {}`, update that in your http_login method, and then pass in the env explicitly as in `get '/', {}, env`.

Comment: Expanding on the above, which works for request and controller specs: https://gist.github.com/4158961

Comment: +1 for the gist from Matt Connolly; it solved my problem when nothing else did. BTW, I tried to use the Rack::Test authorize method - didn't work.

Comment: I get     Failure/Error: @request.env['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token.encode_credentials("test_access1")
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass when I try to use this.. why ?

Comment: A slightly more convenient take on this: https://gist.github.com/lehresman/794f261708c82962763f

Comment: It's worth mentioning, that you can also pass auth info directly as a 3rd argument:

`get '/repp/v1/contacts', { limit: 1, details: true }, { 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' => encoded_auth_key }`

Answer (score 20):

Sorry I didn't search enough, the solution seems to be the following:

```
describe "GET 'index'" do
  it "should be successful" do
    @request.env["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"] = "Basic " + Base64::encode64("username:password")
    get 'index'
    response.should be_success
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8):

Some answers suggest to set `request.env` which is unsafe, because request can be `nil` and you will end up with `private method env' called for nil:NilClass`, especially when run single tests with `rspec -e`

Correct approach will be:

```
def http_login
  user = 'user'
  password = 'passw'
  {
    HTTP_AUTHORIZATION: ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic.encode_credentials(user,password)
  }
end

get 'index', nil, http_login

post 'index', {data: 'post-data'}, http_login
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the only approach that worked for my system tests using Capybara.

Answer (score 8):

For me, with Rails 6, I need keyword arguments for rspec get method like .. `get route, params: params, headers: headers`

**Auth Helper method**

```
module AuthHelper
  def headers(options = {})
    user = ENV['BASIC_AUTH_USER']
    pw = ENV['BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD']

    { HTTP_AUTHORIZATION: ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic.encode_credentials(user,pw) }
  end
  def auth_get(route, params = {})
    get route, params: params, headers: headers
  end
end
```

and the **rspec request test.**

```
describe HomeController, type: :request do    
  include AuthHelper

  describe "GET 'index'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      auth_get 'index'
      expect(response).to be_successful
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 4):

When using Rspec to test Grape APIs, the following syntax works

```
        post :create, {:entry => valid_attributes}, valid_session
```

where valid_session is

```
{'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' => credentials}
```

and

```
credentials = ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token.encode_credentials("test_access1")
```

Answer (score 4):

These are great solutions for controller and request specs.

For feature tests using Capybara, here is a solution to make HTTP Basic authentication work:

**spec/support/when_authenticated.rb**

```
RSpec.shared_context 'When authenticated' do
  background do
    authenticate
  end

  def authenticate
    if page.driver.browser.respond_to?(:authorize)
      # When headless
      page.driver.browser.authorize(username, password)
    else
      # When javascript test
      visit "http://#{username}:#{password}@#{host}:#{port}/"     
     end
  end

  def username
    # Your value here. Replace with string or config location
    Rails.application.secrets.http_auth_username
  end

  def password
    # Your value here. Replace with string or config location
    Rails.application.secrets.http_auth_password
  end

  def host
    Capybara.current_session.server.host
  end

  def port
    Capybara.current_session.server.port
  end
end
```

Then, in your spec:

```
feature 'User does something' do
  include_context 'When authenticated'

  # test examples
end
```

Comment: Very helpful ! :)

Comment: Doesn't work, in Chrome, IE and Safari (at least) [you can't log in http auth with a url anymore](https://medium.com/@lmakarov/say-goodbye-to-urls-with-embedded-credentials-b051f6c7b6a3)

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
stub_request(method, url).with(
  headers: { 'Authorization' => /Basic */ }
).to_return(
  status: status, body: 'stubbed response', headers: {}
)
```

Use **gem webmock**

you can tighten verification by change:

```
/Basic */ -> "Basic #{Base64.strict_encode64([user,pass].join(':')).chomp}"
```

URL - can be a regular expression

Comment: I think you don't need `chomp` in last snippet, because `strict_encode64` does not add newlines as [doc says](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/stdlibs/base64/Base64.html#method-i-strict_encode64)