# HTTP Digest + Rspec

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, rspec, http-digest

I have a pretty basic HTTP Digest Authentication setup on my Rails 3 app. It mostly follows examples found in the [Rails Controller Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#http-digest-authentication):

My ApplicationController has a before_filter:

```
def digest_authenticate
  success = authenticate_or_request_with_http_digest("Application") do |username|
    APP_CONFIG["admin"]
  end
end
```

This all works great. Pages are protected as they should be.

I'm now trying to test this in RSpec and failing miserably.

I followed [this SO accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13426529/writing-a-test-method-for-http-digest-authentication) and put the `authenticate_with_http_digest` method in a support file. Here's my actual test:

```
describe DashboardController do
  describe "GET 'index'" do
    it "returns http success" do
      authenticate_with_http_digest(foo, bar, baz)

      visit root_path
      response.should be_success
      response.code.should == '200'
    end
  end
end
```

A few problems:

1. The tests are passing every time, whether or not I call `authenticate_with_http_digest`
2. The arguments I'm passing to `authenticate_with_http_digest` are bogus, and don't seem to matter. Shouldn't these need to match what I have stored in `APP_CONFIG["admin"]`?
3. If I print out the value of `success` from my `digest_authenticate` before_filter, it always prints out 401, even if I do pass the correct parameters to my rspec helper.

Any ideas how to effectively test HTTP Digest Authentication?

Thanks!

Comment: In a controller test you should be using `get :index` rather than `visit root_path`. The visit approach is a request spec/capybara tool not a controller testing tool.

Comment: ahh, perfect! Please put this as an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For controller tests you should use the `get :index` call rather than the `visit root_path` call. This will work for any valid combination of HTTP verbs and Rails actions you are controller testing.

The `visit` method is part of Capybara and should be used in request specs only.