# rails rspec integration_tests and http authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, basic-authentication

I am using Rspec 2 and capybara and defined the basic integration test, i.e.

```
describe "EeRequisitions" do
  describe "GET /ee_requisitions" do
    it "works! (now write some real specs)" do
      get ee_requisitions_path
      response.status.should be(200)
    end
  end
end
```

Since the app uses HTTP basic authentication and since capybara says it includes Rack::Test, I expected that adding the line:

```
authorize 'user', 'password'
```

would handle it (I've since lost the stackoverflow post that told me that). Unfortunately it didn't - it kept throwing a 'method not found' error.  I finally found the solution in a comment to this post: [Rails/Rspec Make tests pass with http basic authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768718/rails-rspec-make-tests-to-pass-with-http-basic-authentication) where Matt Connelly pointed me to this gist: https://gist.github.com/mattconnolly/4158961 which finally solved my problem.

However, I'm still wondering why the Rack::Test approach failed as it seems to have worked for others.

Answer (score 0):

Does including the line

```
include Rack::Test::Methods
```

at the top of the tests make a difference?

Comment: Sorry, no. And not only does that test still fail, but all the other tests in that group now fail as well with the message: undefined local variable or method `app' for #<EeRequisitionMailer:0x000000049293a8>