# How do I make including a custom module in an RSpec test work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I am trying to include a custom module into an RSpec test.  However, I keep getting errors telling me it can't find my module, it says NameError: uninitialized constant AuthHelper.

I have been trying to follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/68669816/5568244

I didn't know where to put the the module so I created a folder called specs/support/ and a file called auth_helper.rb in it and put `module AuthHelper ...etc... end` in that

I have tried simply including it in the test

spec/requests/topics_specs.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'
include AuthHelper
```

which i expected to be able to just automatically find the module in the support folder but it didn't.  Should it?  Does RSpec look in specific places?

I also tried to set up the rails_helper.rb file to include it

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include(AuthHelper, :type => :request) 
end
```

This still didn't work.

What am i missing? How should this work?

Comment: Rails/RSpec doesn't autoload the `spec/support` dir, so you need to require it in your `RSpec.configure` first:   `require './spec/support/auth_helper'`

Comment: I have added it in spec-helper.rb but i am getting:  `NoMethodError:
       undefined method \`get_auth' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::TopicsAPI:0x00007faf73d5c210>`

Comment: In that case, you likely need to use `config.extend(AuthHelper, :type => :request)` since it sounds like you're trying to use your helper methods outside of the examples.