# Rails rspec feature itegration testing for basic auhentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, integration-testing, basic-authentication

```
class MenucardController < ApplicationController

  http_basic_authenticate_with name: 'admin', password: 'password'

  def index
    @menu_items = CsvFileTest.find_each(batch_size: 10)
  end
end
```

I have a basic authentication in my rails app, how do i test it in feature automated testing.?

I tried this and many other methods too

```
page.driver.browser.basic_authorize('admin', 'password')
```

but authentication testing is not passing successful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rails/Rspec Make tests pass with http basic authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768718/rails-rspec-make-tests-pass-with-http-basic-authentication)